# angular ui modal after close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

Is there a way I can call a function after a modal window got called (no matter if it happened with a button or by clicking on the backdrop)

```
var dialog, options;

options = {
  windowClass: "lightBox"
  templateUrl: "url to the template",
  controller: "some random controller",
  scope: $scope
});

$("body").css({
  'overflow': 'hidden'
});

dialog = $modal.open(options);

dialog.result.then(function() {
  $("body").css({
    'overflow': 'auto'
  });
});
```

I want that everytime the modal windows closes the function in the result.then promise get executed. Now it just executes when i close the modal manually my $modalInstance.close(). But if i click on the backdrop this method doesn't get called

any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I will assume that you are using the Modal dialogs from angular-ui. But before going into the details a bit of documentation around promises in AngularJS is needed. You need to know that every **then** function can accept 3 parameters as such :

```
then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)
```

- **successCallback** is executed when the promise is resolved.
- **errorCallback** is executed when the promise is rejected.
- **notifyCallback** is executed when notified.

In the case of angular-ui's modal, clicking on the backdrop will result in a rejected promise. With this in mind, your code could be changed to :

```
dialog.result.then(function () {
  alert('Modal success at:' + new Date());
}, function () {
  alert('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

You can see a working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/k3SE08xzvHe6dUKYhNlN?p=preview)

Answer (score 20):

Angular 1.2 supports promises with a [`finally(callback)`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback):

```
dialog.result.finally(function() {
    alert('clean up resources');
});
```

Check out the working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Lspil?p=preview).

Comment: Remember `finally` won't work in IE8. Possible fix here - http://www.antonydenyer.co.uk/blog/2014/08/22/angularjs-decorator-to-support-ie8-catch/