# angular strap modal on hide event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

Currently, I m trying to fire an event when I close my modal. I found this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k3SE08xzvHe6dUKYhNlN?p=preview) with the functionality what I want to create. When  I try to recreate this plunker in my own js file, it doesn't seem to work. The code below is a part of my main js file. If a button is pressed this piece of code is fired.

```
        function editActivity(activityId) {
        var editModal = $modal({
            templateUrl: '/DesktopModules/Name/Angular/ViewModels/main/edit.html',
            locals: {
                activityId: activityId
            },
            controller: 'editCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            show: true,
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static'
        });
        editModal.result.then('modal.hide', function (result) {
            alert("finally")
            if (result === true) {
                // Reload the list if the selected was updated.
                searchActivities();
            }
        });
    return null;
    }
```

This code creates a modal but I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at mainController.editActivity
```

When I try to close the modal a new error message is given. The code for the closing the modal is:

```
 function saveActivity() {
        var updateData = {
            Id: vm.EditActivity.Id,
            Zipcode: vm.EditActivity.Zipcode,
            AreaType: vm.EditActivity.AreaType,
            Activities: vm.EditActivity.Activities
        }
        apiService.updateActivity(updateData);
        $modal.close(true);
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
$modal.close is not a function
at editController.saveActivity
```

I found several quetion related to this subject like
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228725/capture-hide-event-in-modal-of-angular-strap) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962536/angular-ui-modal-after-close-event) but none of those solutions seems to work for me. Keep in mind that i m working with angular-strap.

---

I found a solution after looking of the possible options of modal([site](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals)).

One of the options of modal is: Onhide. When the modal is hidden, it will fire a function. My new main js file looks the following:

```
    function editActivity(activityId) {
        var editModal = $modal({
            templateUrl: '/DesktopModules/name/Cogas/Angular/ViewModels/main/edit.html',
            locals: {
                activityId: activityId
            },
            controller: 'editCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            show: true,
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            onHide: function () {
                searchActivities();
            }
        });
    }
```

I removed the *$modal.close()* from the modal js and added *hide()*. This is probaly not the best way to do this, but it is sufficient for me.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` means that you should return your promise to the calling function. I'm currently looking at the other errors.

Comment: @ZombieChowder you are right and i tried to fixed this to include a return in the code. Still getting the same error. I updated the question to include my "fix".

Comment: @ZombieChowder doesn't change anything

Comment: can you create a `jsFiddle` by any chance? It's quite difficult to debug your code as it is.

Comment: @ZombieChowder i think i found a solution. I don't know why i didn't found this before. I update my question to include my fix.

Comment: Glad you found a solution and sorry that I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @ZombieChowder thank you for your time. Most of the time, it is really helpfull to just type it out and get some feedback.